# Is there plugin for Notepad++ to tweak how blocks of code highlight?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

[image]

Instead of dotted line I want solid line on side. Or even something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "indentation guides". Don't know NPP plugun. It's configurable in editors:

- HippoEdit (even with colors: red/green/etc-- option exists),
- SynWrite (only style of line).